# Visual equation links in amsmath align environments

Tags: align, amsmath

I would like to "visually link" equations in the `align`

Since a picture is worth many words, here's an example I made in MS Paint to show what I mean:

[image]

How could one achieve this? A MWE for testing purposes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}
    First, let us solve the following recursion formula:
        $$ F_{n + 1} = \alpha F_{n} + \beta$$
        \begin{align*}
            &\quad F_{n + 1} = \alpha F_{n} + \beta \\
            &\equiv \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n + 1} t^{n} = \alpha \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n} t^{n} + \beta t^{n} \\
            &\equiv t^{-1} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n + 1} t^{n + 1} = \alpha \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n}t^n + \beta t^n \\
            &\equiv \phi(t) - F_{0} = \alpha t\phi(t) + \frac{\alpha t}{1 - \beta t} \\
            &\equiv \phi(t) (1 - \alpha t) =  \frac{\alpha t}{1 - \beta t} + F_0\frac{1 - \beta t}{1 - \beta t} \\
            &\quad \\
            &\quad F_{n + 1} = \alpha F_{n} + \beta \\
            &\equiv \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n + 1} t^{n} = \alpha \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n} t^{n} + \beta t^{n} \\
            &\equiv t^{-1} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n + 1} t^{n + 1} = \alpha \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n}t^n + \beta t^n \\
            &\equiv \phi(t) - F_{0} = \alpha t\phi(t) + \frac{\alpha t}{1 - \beta t} \\
            &\equiv \phi(t) (1 - \alpha t) =  \frac{\alpha t}{1 - \beta t} + F_0\frac{1 - \beta t}{1 - \beta t} \\
            &\quad \\
            &\quad F_{n + 1} = \alpha F_{n} + \beta \\
            &\equiv \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n + 1} t^{n} = \alpha \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n} t^{n} + \beta t^{n} \\
            &\equiv t^{-1} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n + 1} t^{n + 1} = \alpha \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n}t^n + \beta t^n \\
            &\equiv \phi(t) - F_{0} = \alpha t\phi(t) + \frac{\alpha t}{1 - \beta t} \\
            &\equiv \phi(t) (1 - \alpha t) =  \frac{\alpha t}{1 - \beta t} + F_0\frac{1 - \beta t}{1 - \beta t} \\
            &\quad \\
            &\quad F_{n + 1} = \alpha F_{n} + \beta \\
            &\equiv \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n + 1} t^{n} = \alpha \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n} t^{n} + \beta t^{n} \\
            &\equiv t^{-1} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n + 1} t^{n + 1} = \alpha \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n}t^n + \beta t^n \\
            &\equiv \phi(t) - F_{0} = \alpha t\phi(t) + \frac{\alpha t}{1 - \beta t} \\
            &\equiv \phi(t) (1 - \alpha t) =  \frac{\alpha t}{1 - \beta t} + F_0\frac{1 - \beta t}{1 - \beta t} \\
            &\quad \\
            &\quad F_{n + 1} = \alpha F_{n} + \beta \\
            &\equiv \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n + 1} t^{n} = \alpha \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n} t^{n} + \beta t^{n} \\
            &\equiv t^{-1} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n + 1} t^{n + 1} = \alpha \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n}t^n + \beta t^n \\
            &\equiv \phi(t) - F_{0} = \alpha t\phi(t) + \frac{\alpha t}{1 - \beta t} \\
            &\equiv \phi(t) (1 - \alpha t) =  \frac{\alpha t}{1 - \beta t} + F_0\frac{1 - \beta t}{1 - \beta t} \\
            &\quad \\
            &\quad F_{n + 1} = \alpha F_{n} + \beta \\
            &\equiv \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n + 1} t^{n} = \alpha \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n} t^{n} + \beta t^{n} \\
            &\equiv t^{-1} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n + 1} t^{n + 1} = \alpha \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n}t^n + \beta t^n \\
            &\equiv \phi(t) - F_{0} = \alpha t\phi(t) + \frac{\alpha t}{1 - \beta t} \\
            &\equiv \phi(t) (1 - \alpha t) =  \frac{\alpha t}{1 - \beta t} + F_0\frac{1 - \beta t}{1 - \beta t}
        \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It can be done easily using tikzpicture with overlay option and tikzmarks... If you want to check this idea (or any other) just add some code (a MWE) to complete

Comment: @koleygr done! i added the mwe that produced the output i used to make the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution according to my comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\tikzmark#1{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]\coordinate(#1);\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
 $$ F_{n + 1} = \alpha F_{n} + \beta$$
        \begin{align*}
            &\tikzmark{A}\quad F_{n + 1} = \alpha F_{n} + \beta \\
            &\tikzmark{C}\equiv \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n + 1} t^{n} = \alpha \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n} t^{n} + \beta t^{n} \\
            &\equiv t^{-1} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n + 1} t^{n + 1} = \alpha \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n}t^n + \beta t^n \\
            &\equiv \phi(t) - F_{0} = \alpha t\phi(t) + \frac{\alpha t}{1 - \beta t} \\
          &\tikzmark{D}\equiv \phi(t) (1 - \alpha t) =  \frac{\alpha t}{1 - \beta t} + F_0\frac{1 - \beta t}{1 - \beta t} \\
            &\quad \\
            &\quad F_{n + 1} = \alpha F_{n} + \beta \\
      &\tikzmark{B}\equiv \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n + 1} t^{n} = \alpha \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n} t^{n} + \beta t^{n} \\
            &\equiv t^{-1} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n + 1} t^{n + 1} = \alpha \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n}t^n + \beta t^n \\
            &\equiv \phi(t) - F_{0} = \alpha t\phi(t) + \frac{\alpha t}{1 - \beta t} \\
            &\equiv \phi(t) (1 - \alpha t) =  \frac{\alpha t}{1 - \beta t} + F_0\frac{1 - \beta t}{1 - \beta t} \\
            &\quad \\
            &\quad F_{n + 1} = \alpha F_{n} + \beta \\
            &\equiv \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n + 1} t^{n} = \alpha \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n} t^{n} + \beta t^{n} \\
            &\equiv t^{-1} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n + 1} t^{n + 1} = \alpha \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n}t^n + \beta t^n \\
            &\equiv \phi(t) - F_{0} = \alpha t\phi(t) + \frac{\alpha t}{1 - \beta t} \\
            &\equiv \phi(t) (1 - \alpha t) =  \frac{\alpha t}{1 - \beta t} + F_0\frac{1 - \beta t}{1 - \beta t} \\
            &\quad \\
            &\quad F_{n + 1} = \alpha F_{n} + \beta \\
            &\equiv \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n + 1} t^{n} = \alpha \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n} t^{n} + \beta t^{n} \\
            &\equiv t^{-1} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n + 1} t^{n + 1} = \alpha \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n}t^n + \beta t^n \\
            &\equiv \phi(t) - F_{0} = \alpha t\phi(t) + \frac{\alpha t}{1 - \beta t} \\
            &\equiv \phi(t) (1 - \alpha t) =  \frac{\alpha t}{1 - \beta t} + F_0\frac{1 - \beta t}{1 - \beta t} \\
            &\quad \\
            &\quad F_{n + 1} = \alpha F_{n} + \beta \\
            &\equiv \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n + 1} t^{n} = \alpha \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n} t^{n} + \beta t^{n} \\
            &\equiv t^{-1} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n + 1} t^{n + 1} = \alpha \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n}t^n + \beta t^n \\
            &\equiv \phi(t) - F_{0} = \alpha t\phi(t) + \frac{\alpha t}{1 - \beta t} \\
            &\equiv \phi(t) (1 - \alpha t) =  \frac{\alpha t}{1 - \beta t} + F_0\frac{1 - \beta t}{1 - \beta t} \\
            &\quad \\
            &\quad F_{n + 1} = \alpha F_{n} + \beta \\
            &\equiv \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n + 1} t^{n} = \alpha \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n} t^{n} + \beta t^{n} \\
            &\equiv t^{-1} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n + 1} t^{n + 1} = \alpha \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} F_{n}t^n + \beta t^n \\
            &\equiv \phi(t) - F_{0} = \alpha t\phi(t) + \frac{\alpha t}{1 - \beta t} \\
            &\equiv \phi(t) (1 - \alpha t) =  \frac{\alpha t}{1 - \beta t} + F_0\frac{1 - \beta t}{1 - \beta t}
        \end{align*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw[-,red] (A)--([xshift=-0.6cm]A)|-(B);
   \draw[-,blue] (C)--([xshift=-0.4cm]C)|-(D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Note, that the lines starts from the center of every row (every math line) and 
may be have to be adjusted to be centered with `\equiv` symbol.

May be I can automate this later if you interested. (A `yshift=2mm` option before the letter of the tikzmark in the draw command can fix it manually)